# Best way to embed Flex-based swf into pure-AS3 project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, embed, flash-builder

I'm working on a AS3 project that required a lot of UI, since Flex was used for time-saving for this part we ended up having a Flex Project (UI) and pure AS3 one (All BackEnd) or, in other words, two different .swf files.

Currently I can successfully comunicate both of them using a common interface and by loading the UI .swf into the AS3 .swf using a Loader class:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(“CustomUIModule.swf”);
```

The actual code contains listeners for SystemManagerHandler so Flex doesn't complain.

Since we are delivering two different files it is not really practical whenever we release a build of the project. For this case the meta tag **[Embed]** seems to be a better way to achieve this (With no satisfactory results to date).

With the above information (hopefully I made myself clear enough) what would be the best approach to ultimately generate a single swf? Or how should we properly implement the [Embed] tag for Flex swf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid loading SWF into another SWF It just doesnt seem right to me, especially if I have control over all the SWFs. If it was me I would integrate everything into one fat flex project. After all isn't this what OOP is all about.

Comment: I agree with you, however this particular project required this type of approach due to time constraints.